# Как универсально отловить исключения из Listener'ов в Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2, события

Есть у нас EventDispatcher, которым мы пользуемся следующим образом

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch('order.after.creation', new OrderAfterCreationEvent($subOrder));
```

Подписываемся на это событие в services.yml

```
listener.orderCreation:
  class: ...\Listener\OrderCreationListener
  arguments: [...]
tags:
  - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: order.after.creation, method: onOrderCreation }
```

И этот слушатель довольно сложен и выкидывает исключение

```
class OrderCreationListener extends AbstractListener
{
    public function onOrderCreation(OrderAfterCreationEvent $event)
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

И теперь главный вопрос, как лучше всего отлавливать такие исключения? В голову приходят несколько идей:

1. обрамить код Listener'а в try{}catch и тогда он сам решит как действовать, НО ведь есть нерадивые программисты, которые могут добавить свой Listener, не обрамив его в try{}catch, и тогда мы получим необработанный exception, который сломает правильно отработавший код (создание заказа)
2. обрамить метод dispatch в try{}catch. Но тогда одна строчка превращается в несколько, а если надо обрабатывать исключения? Тогда вообще мрак... Да и тем более надо делать везде, о чем тоже нерадивый программист может забыть. И так же при исключении первого Listener'а все остальные Listener'ы не отработают.
3. унаследоваться от ContainerAwareEventDispatcher и переопределить метод doDispatch

ContainerAwareEventDispatcher::doDispatch()

```
protected function doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, Event $event)
{
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        call_user_func($listener, $event, $eventName, $this);
        if ($event->isPropagationStopped()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

новый doDispatch()

```
protected function doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, Event $event)
{
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        try {
            call_user_func($listener, $event, $eventName, $this);    
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // handle and log $e
        }

        if ($event->isPropagationStopped()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

И в итоге мы получим универсальную обработку исключений от Listener'ов, но переопределим метод и будем вынуждены поддерживать его.

Я больше склоняюсь к 3-ему решению. Но может быть я что-то пропустил, подскажите как вы решаете такую проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие-то замудренные шаги описываете. В Symfony есть стандартный способ: определить listener на событие `kernel.exception`. Это событие обрабатывает все исключения, выкинутые внутри `AppKernel::handle()`.

В нем можно обработать любое исключение, как пожелаете. Пример такой обработки можно найти в [официальной документации Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html).

Comment: Но мне нужно обработать исключения от listener'ов и продолжить работу, а это будет невозможно, если воспользоваться данным решением